# How to add a new value to a Firestore field in a document in addition to the previous value?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a function that checks if a collection in Firestore exists and if it exist I want it to add the value given by the user to the value stored in the document inside the collection

My approach:

```
  items.forEach(item=>
  
      User &&  db.collection("users").doc(Uid).collection("basket").where( "id" , "==" , item.id)
      .get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
          
                 // DO SOMETHING

        }
         else {
         
          db.collection("users").doc(Uid).collection("basket").where("id" == item.id)
          .get().then((docs) => {
        
            docs.forEach((doc) =>{ doc.ref.set({
              quantity : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(item.quantity)
            })}).then(setLocked(true))
          
           
        })
               
        }
    })
    )
```

however it shows the following error :

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ut')
```

I doubled check the code and it turns out that the error comes from the beginning of the query the `else` statement however there is nothing wrong with it

Comment: If I understand your question properly you could either use the merge option:https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document or/and es6 destructuring to add a new value to an existing Map or Array.

Comment: No merge option does not work because I cannot call `set` on a collection @Stf_F

Comment: Of course, but your question was related to the possible options available to combine values in a document.

Answer (score 1):

As Stf_F commented, you can either pass `merge: true` to the `set` call:

```
docs.forEach((doc) =>{ 
  doc.ref.set({
    quantity : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(item.quantity)
  }, { merge: true }) // 
})
```

or you can use `update`:

```
docs.forEach((doc) =>{ 
  doc.ref.update({ // 
    quantity : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(item.quantity)
  })
})
```

The `.then(setLocked(true))` makes no sense, since `forEach` doesn't return a promise.